# ¿Cómo puedo castear un Date en Java?

Tags: java, string, date, cast

Estoy haciendo una app en Java y tengo en la base de datos una columna llamada *fecha_pedido* con datos tipo Date
En Java lo he declarado en el modelo *private Date fechaPedido;*
Al hacer las pruebas le paso un *String* "2009-12-10" que se que está en la base de datos
¿Cómo puedo castear la fecha de Date a *String*? ¿Dónde lo tengo que castear? ¿En la prueba que estoy haciendo?
Muchas gracias

Comment: Todo eso es muy relativo. Usas algún framework para manejar la base de datos? Cómo accedes a dichos datos? Muchos gestores que usan JPA y similares hacen la conversión por ti... Sin saber qué estás haciendo ni cómo, es imposible ayudarte sin inventarme la respuesta.

Answer (score -1):

suponiendo que ya tienes la fecha en Date, lo que debes hacer es darle formato y pasarlo por un SimpleDateFormat, de la siguiente manera:

```
    Date fecha = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat formatoFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    System.out.println(formatoFecha.format(fecha));
```

Comment: Evita responder a preguntas en donde el autor de la misma no haya demostrado lo que ha investigado hasta el momento, y/o a preguntas del tipo _gimme the codez_ ("dameh el código"). Como verás, incluso la pregunta era un duplicado de otra. Lee [answer].